# Nextjs with Chakra optional Href

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

The current Issue is, after making the **href** property from nextjs as **optional**, and setting a default value for **href** as empty string. being on a certain page like /profile fills the empty string with the current href.

I want to use it like this:

```
<NavItem icon={LogoutIcon} onClick={handleLogout} marginTop='auto'>
          Log out
</NavItem>
```

Link.tsx

```
import { PropsWithChildren, HTMLProps } from 'react';
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { LinkProps as NextLinkProps } from 'next/dist/client/link';
import {
  Link as ChakraLink,
  LinkProps as ChakraLinkProps,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

export type NextChakraLinkProps = PropsWithChildren<
  NextLinkProps &
    Omit<ChakraLinkProps, 'as'> &
    Omit<NextLinkProps & HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>, 'href'> & {
      href?: string;
    }
>;

export const NextChakraLink = ({
  href = '',
  as,
  replace,
  scroll,
  shallow,
  prefetch,
  children,
  ...chakraProps
}: NextChakraLinkProps) => {
  return (
    <NextLink
      passHref={true}
      href={href}
      as={as}
      replace={replace}
      scroll={scroll}
      shallow={shallow}
      prefetch={prefetch}
    >
      <ChakraLink color='darkGreen' _hover={{ color: 'blue' }} {...chakraProps}>
        {children}
      </ChakraLink>
    </NextLink>
  );
};
```

Comment: The href prop is a required prop for the NextLink component. What we see here might be the fallback behavior. Are you trying to use a custom link component? In that case, you can check this out. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag

Comment: How are you using the `NextChakraLink` for the link where the issue occurs?